# How to use foreach with if condition for given lists?

Tags: if-statement, foreach, range, tcl

```
set A {50 98 76 34 67}
set B {12 23 48 59 65}

foreach c $A d $B {
    if { 40 <= $c && $c <= 60 && 20 <= $d && $d <= 30 } {
        puts $c
        puts $d
    }
}
```

I am not getting any output from above code. The output required from the above code should be number 50 34 23.

Comment: Try putting `puts "c=$c, d=$d"` immediately before the `if` to see what the code is considering.

Comment: You'll need to use OR instead of AND to join the "$c in range" and the "$d in range" expressions. Use parentheses to control order of operations.

Comment: ` set A {50 98 76 34 67}
set B {12 23 48 59 65}

foreach c $A d $B { 
    if { ( 40 <= $c && $c <= 60 ) || ( 20 <= $d && $d <= 30 ) } {
      puts $c
      puts $d
    }
} '   so I modify my syntax. But now I get output as 50 12 98 23. it should be only 50 and 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your problem by putting another if.

```
set A {50 98 76 34 67}
set B {12 23 48 59 65}

foreach c $A d $B {
    if {40 <= $c && $c <= 60} {
        puts $c
    } 

    if {20 <= $d && $d <= 30} {
        puts $d
    }
}

# 50
# 23
```

If you want if or if to appear on 34, modify the first conditional to accept numbers greater than 30 and not 40.

```
set A {50 98 76 34 67}
set B {12 23 48 59 65}

foreach c $A d $B {
    if {30 <= $c && $c <= 60} {
        puts $c
    } 

    if {20 <= $d && $d <= 30} {
        puts $d
    }
}

# 50
# 23
# 34
```