# how to use filter the numbers from list using foreach and if?

Tags: if-statement, foreach, tcl

```
set A { 50 98 76 34 67}
set B { 12 23 48 59 65}

foreach c $A d $B {
    if { (40 <= $c && $c <= 60) || (20 <= $d && $d <= 30) } {
      puts $c
      puts $d
    }
}
```

I am getting output as 50 12 98 23 but it should be 50 and 23.

Comment: Why? Consider when c=50 and d=12: c is between 40 and 60 so you print both c and d. Do you need two separate if statements?

Comment: You asked this exact question earlier:

[How to use foreach with if condition for given lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73895035/how-to-use-foreach-with-if-condition-for-given-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be quite confused as to what the consequences of the code you have written really are.

That `foreach` presents the pair-wise elements from the two lists to the body script via the variables. That is, you get `50,12`, then `98,23`, then `76,48`, ...

Your body script consists of a single `if` with *one* test (which happens to be a compound expression, but it is still a single test overall), and will run its body if that test is true.

The body prints both variables.

That is what you have told the language to do. It has done it for you. The computer can't read your mind; the only way it can know what to do is because someone has told it what to do.

---

I guess you might like:

```
set A { 50 98 76 34 67}
set B { 12 23 48 59 65}

foreach c $A d $B {
    if {40 <= $c && $c <= 60} {
        puts $c
    }
    if {20 <= $d && $d <= 30} {
        puts $d
    }
}
```

Or even this:

```
proc when {value in range from to do body} {
    if {$from <= $value && $value <= $to} {
        uplevel 1 $body
    }
}

set A { 50 98 76 34 67}
set B { 12 23 48 59 65}

foreach c $A d $B {
    when $c in range 40 60 do {puts $c}
    when $d in range 20 30 do {puts $d}
}
```

Once you understand why this works, you'll be much further on with your understanding of both Tcl and programming in general.

Answer (score 0):

Is this meant to be a pairwise XOR (exclusive-or)? If so, the inclusive-or `||` operator will not help.

You might consider rewriting to:

```
set A {50 98 76 34 67}
set B {12 23 48 59 65}

foreach c $A d $B {
  if {40 <= $c && $c <= 60} {
    puts $c
  } elseif {20 <= $d && $d <= 30} {
    puts $d
  }
}
```